# Numpy: Vectorize mathematical formula with indices

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I'm simulating a Markov Birth&Death process using the following equations: (sorry, MathJax is not available).

```
$ b_i = \textbf{P}(X_{n+1} = i +1 | X_n = i)$

$ d_i = \textbf{P}(X_{n+1} = i -1 | X_n = i)$

$\pi_i b_i = \pi_{i+1} d_{i+1}$

$\pi_i = \pi_0 \frac{b_0 b_1 b_2 \dots b_{i-1}}{d_1 d_2 \dots d_i},$ $i = 1, \dots , m$

$\sum \pi_i = 1$
```

I used this code to compute the pi_i's:

```
import numpy as np

m = 10
# b_0 = 0.5, b_1, ..., b_{m-1} = 0.25
b = 0.25 * np.ones(m-1)
b[0] = 0.5

# d1, ..., d_{m-1} = 0.25, d_m = 0.5
d = 0.25 * np.ones(m-1) # d[0] corresponds to d_1 
d[-1] = 0.5

pi = np.ones(m)

for i in range(1, len(pi)):
    #print(f'i={i}, b[0:i] = {b[0:i]}, d[0:i] =  {d[0:i]}')
    pi[i] = pi[0] * np.prod(b[0:i]) / np.prod(d[0:i])

pi_normalized = pi / pi.sum()
print(pi_normalized)
```

I'm interested in vectorizing this for loop:

```
for i in range(1, len(pi)):
    #print(f'i={i}, b[0:i] = {b[0:i]}, d[0:i] =  {d[0:i]}')
    pi[i] = pi[0] * np.prod(b[0:i]) / np.prod(d[0:i])
```

**Question-1: How to "vectorize" the for-loop above? By "vectorizing" I mean not using `numpy.vectorize`. Instead I think of speeding up the code by using array operations, like c_i = a_i  b_i  --> c = a * b where a,b and c are arrays.**

**Question-2: Is there a general method/algorithm to "vectorize" mathematical formulas with indices?**

Comment: If `b` and `d` are probabilities you shouldn't multiply them. If they are small enough or `m` is pretty large you will get numerical underflow (values which are pretty much zero). Check [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/253319/217516) for more details

Comment: Thanks a lot! Of course, a log-sum-exp approach is much better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use cumprod for this, here is sudo code which may work

```py
result = pi[0] * np.cumprod(b) / np.cumprod(d)
```

I think question-2 is quite vague, That depends on type of mathematical formula you have. Generally to vectorize mathematical operations involving indexes you can use functions like np.cumsum, np.cumprod, np.arange depending upon what operation can be applied to whole array. You can get some idea on how to use vectorization and broadcasts (important part of vectorization) [here](https://medium.com/@dev.b.khadka/learn-numpy-by-playing-concepts-indexing-vectorization-and-more-efea45485f19), under broadcast and vectorization section

Comment: Thanks, `pi[1:] = pi[0] * np.cumprod(b) / np.cumprod(d)` worked.

Comment: Do, you have an answer for my second question too?

Comment: @MichaelS there's no generalized way to vectorize iterative systems.  If the system can be reduced to `cumproduct`, `cumsum` and `diff` operations (or any [`ufunc`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/ufuncs.html) really) it's vectorizable.  But  in general that's not always the case (especially for most elliptical functions where iteration is necessary to solve them).